# @PreAuthorize annotation does not work in Resful web service

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, annotations

I have Java Restful web service with Spring Security, JAX-RS Jersey. I use @PreAuthorize annotations for method security, but it doesn't work.

I have method, which use annotation @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"), but users with ROLE_USER, also have access to this method.

Can anybody help me?

**Spring version**

```
<spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

My **spring-security-context.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/list" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/add" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/update" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/**" method="DELETE" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/users/get/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/orders/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER')"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout"/>
</http>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
                                 pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>


<beans:bean id="customUserService" class="com.bankproject.services.CustomUserDetailService"/>
<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="orderDAO" class="com.bankproject.DAO.Impl.OrderOutputDAOImpl"/>
<beans:bean id="orderManager" class="com.bankproject.services.OrderService"/>
```

My **OutputOrderDAOImpl.java**

```
public class OrderOutputDAOImpl implements OrderOutputDAO {

   @Override
   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
   public List<OrderOutputObject> getOrdersByUsername(String username) throws SQLException {
       List<OrderObject> orders = orderDAO.getOrdersByUsername(username);
       return getOutputOrders(orders);
   }

}
```

My **OrderService.java**

```
@Path("/orders")
public class OrderService {

     @GET
     @Path("/{username}")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public List<OrderOutputObject> getOrdersForUser(@PathParam("username") String username){
         List<OrderOutputObject> orders = new ArrayList<OrderOutputObject>();
         try{
             orders = orderOutputDAO.getOrdersByUsername(username);
         }catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return orders;
     }
}
```